# If an error happens will ajax stop still run?

Tags: jquery

I am wondering if you do an AJAX request and you have a method that should run when the AJAX request stops.  Will the jQuery ajax stop run if the request runs into an error (such as a 500 error) or if say the request times out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [`ajaxStop()` event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) will execute when this happens :)

[It happens in the global `complete` handler](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L617), which executes error or not.

[You can test it out a bit here](http://jsfiddle.net/UbV7k/).

Comment: Nice just wanted to know that not that my jquery loading msg stays on loading and the users can't continue even if the ajax request died along the way.

Comment: @chobo2 - Ah I see, good question...this has come up a number of times on SO, but never a direct question that I can remember...edited the question a bit to make it a bit more google-friendly for future users :)